# How to get unique links in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have the following html which have couple of duplicate href's. How do I extract only the unique links

```
<div class="pages">
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=1" class="active">1</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=2">2</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=3">3</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=4">4</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=5">5</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=2">next &rsaquo;</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=6">last &raquo;</a>
</div> 

# p => is the page that has this html
# The below gives 7 as expected. But I don't need next/last links as they are duplicate    
p.css(".pages a").count

#So I tried uniq which obviously didnt work

p.css(".pages").css("a").uniq            #=> didn't work
p.css(".pages").css("a").to_a.uniq       #=> didn't work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try extracting the "href" attribute from the matching elements (`el.attr('href')`):

```ruby
html = Nokogiri::HTML(your_html_string)
html.css('a').map { |el| el.attr('href') }.uniq
# /search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=1
# /search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=2
# /search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=3
# /search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=4
# /search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=5
# /search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=6
```

Comment: Normalizing the CGI parameter order might be a good idea as well, `/x?a=b&c=d` and `/x?c=d&a=b` are the same URL even though they're different strings.

Answer (score 3):

The same can be done using `#xpath`. I would do as below:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-HTML
<div class="pages">
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=1" class="active">1</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=2">2</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=3">3</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=4">4</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=5">5</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=2">next &rsaquo;</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=6">last &raquo;</a>
</div> 
HTML

doc.xpath("//a/@href").map(&:to_s).uniq
# => ["/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=1",
#     "/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=2",
#     "/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=3",
#     "/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=4",
#     "/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=5",
#     "/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=6"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same job,where uniq value selection is being handled in the `xpath` expression itself:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-HTML
<div class="pages">
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=1" class="active">1</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=2">2</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=3">3</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=4">4</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=5">5</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=2">next &rsaquo;</a>
  <a href="/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=6">last &raquo;</a>
</div> 
HTML

doc.xpath("//a[not(@href = preceding-sibling::a/@href)]/@href").map(&:to_s)
# => ["/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=1",
#     "/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=2",
#     "/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=3",
#     "/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=4",
#     "/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=5",
#     "/search_results.aspx?f=Technology&Page=6"]
```